# How to dynamically implement proxy pattern in flex action script?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, proxy-pattern

I need to implement a proxy pattern for flex action script. The source object contains 40-50 methods, and may keep increasing, so I hope I could avoid implementing individual methods in the source object.

I remember in java, I could use reflection to centralized all the proxy calls, is there any similar mechanism in Flex Action Script?

Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're after, but there's the as3 [Proxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html) class and the Flex [ObjectProxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectProxy.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to accomplish but there is a handy AVM bytecode library from [AS3Commons](http://www.as3commons.org) that allows to create classes on runtime. [There is example how to generate dynamic proxy](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/proxy.html).